# Where celery saves tasks?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

Hy,

Where does Celery (or RabbitMQ) saves scheduled, un-ack messages/tasks? From where they are restored in case of failure?
I understand that it saves the parametrs along with the code. 
How about if the parameters are a few MB, can this be a problem when there are a lot of tasks?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broker (RabbitMQ) takes care about messages store and deliver, so if your consumer fails with pending (un-acked) messages that message will be delivered to other consumer (if any) again. RabbitMQ store entities in memory or on disk.

I didn't get what do you mean

> saves the parameters along with the code

You are talking about message arguments or queue/exchange parameters?

If you meant message arguments they are stored with message body.

Message size in a few MB are OK. The best message size depends of your architecture, say, in some cases message size should be as small as possible and in some they may care 100MB, but too large messages are not what AMQP protocol was designed for.

Comment: Tx zaq,
Yes, I mean message arguments.
But, where un-ack messages are stored on disk? what kind of structure it uses to store theese messages. I would like to know this theory.

Comment: RabbitMQ tries to store messages in memory, but when node run out of memory messages flushed to disk, which lead to poor performance. When node out of memory _and_ disk space, it stop accepting messages. If you want to go deeper - read sources, but if you are an end user and not RabbitMQ developer (probably you not) or academical researcher it less likes that you need such details.